# OnClickListener not detecting click. Class not loading

Tags: java, android, icecast

I'm new to Android and Java development.  I'm trying to make an app that plays an Icecast audio stream.

I found, copied and edited the below code into a class called Audio Stream

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.media.MediaPlayer.OnBufferingUpdateListener;
import android.media.MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;

import java.io.IOException;

public class AudioStream extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

    private Button buttonPlay;

    private MediaPlayer player;

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        initializeUIElements();

        initializeMediaPlayer();
        Log.d("Classloaded", "Class loaded");
    }

    private void initializeUIElements() {

        buttonPlay = findViewById(R.id.PlayPauseButton);
        buttonPlay.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    public void onClick(View v) {
        Log.d("onClick", "On Click worked");
        if (v == buttonPlay) {
            startPlaying();
        }
    }

    private void startPlaying() {
        buttonPlay.setEnabled(false);

        player.prepareAsync();

        player.setOnPreparedListener(new OnPreparedListener() {

            public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
                player.start();
            }
        });

    }

    private void initializeMediaPlayer() {
        player = new MediaPlayer();
        try {
            player.setDataSource("streamURL");
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        player.setOnBufferingUpdateListener(new OnBufferingUpdateListener() {

            public void onBufferingUpdate(MediaPlayer mp, int percent) {
                Log.i("Buffering", "" + percent);
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        if (player.isPlaying()) {
            player.stop();
        }
    }
}
```

When I run the app the neither of the `Log.d` events fire off so I can only assume the class is never loaded and instanced. So I added the tried the following in `MainActivity`

```
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;


public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        AudioStream stream = new AudioStream();
    }
}
```

I know I'm doing something wrong.  How do I get the `AudioStream` class to instance when the app loads so that the `OnClickListener` will work when I press the play button?

Comment: Hello welcome to android-dev. First thing, don't ever instantiate Activities by yourself. If you want to start an activity there is a method `startActivity(Intent intent)` that you use for that. Onto your problem... I couldn't replicate your problem. I turned on a debugger and went step by step and the OnClick event fired without any issues. The code crashed only at `player.prepareAsync()` and it wasn't related to on click. Have you managed to fix your issues?

Comment: No, when I click the Play button nothing happens at all, either in the log or in the app.

Comment: Do I need to start the activity before the click will work?  I don't understand how activities work.

Comment: read and understand https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/intro-activities it will help you. Basically you can start reading here: https://developer.android.com/guide/

Comment: visit this to know how it work https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity

Comment: Ok, so Activity is essentially states like in React.  It also states for onCreate `You must implement this callback, which fires when the system creates your activity.`.  Obviously the Activity is not being created since the `Log.d` I placed there isn't firing.  So where and how would I run the activity?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of :

```
  public void onClick(View v) {
        Log.d("onClick", "On Click worked");
        if (v == buttonPlay) {
            startPlaying();
        }
    }
```

you should do like :

```
  public void onClick(View v) {
        Log.d("onClick", "On Click worked");
        if (v.getId == R.id.PlayPauseButton) {
            startPlaying();
        }
    }
```

Comment: I move the code back into `MainActivity` and then implemented this change that has lead me to the point that N. Matic mentioned with the PrepareAsync error, much further than I had got previously.  Thanks